# Proof of Cauchy's Theorem for abelian groups (Herstein)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

I'm trying to understand a proof to the Cauchy's Theorem mentioned above, and this particular proof I'm reading, from Herstein, claims at some point that given $G$  a finite abelian group and $N$ a subgroup of $G$, if:

- $p \nmid o(N)$, where $p$ is a prime
- $(Nb)^{o(N)} = N$, where $b$ is an element of $G$ and $o(N)$ denotes the order of $N$.
- $(Nb)^p$ = N

Then $Nb = N$

If that really is the case, could you explain to me why, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you denote $o(N)$? The order or the exponent of $N$?

Comment: Regardless of what $o(N)$ means, since $p$ and $o(N)$ are coprime there exist $u,v$ such that $up + v\cdot o(N) = 1$. Then $Nb = (Nb)^{up + v\cdot o(N)} = ((Nb)^p)^u \cdot (Nb^{o(N)})^v = N\cdot N = N$.

Comment: @Bernard, Hi! Thank you very much, I feel very welcome here. Sorry about that, that's the notation the book uses for the order of a group.

Comment: @zarathustra, thank you very much. That was a great insight!

Comment: @zarathustra/ I don't see why $N^u$ or $N^v$ are equal to $N$.

Comment: @Bernard I think $G$ is assumed to be finite. Then $u$ and $v$ can be taken coprime to $o(N)$. But you only need that $N^u=N$, and $u$ is necessarily coprime to $o(N)$.

Comment: @Bernard The condition that N is a group guarantees that it is closed resulting in $N^k = N$ for any k in the integers.

Comment: But that is false! Take thee example of the multiplicative group $(\mathbf Z/r\mathbf Z)^{\times}$, which has order $4$. Its square has order $2$.

Comment: @Bernard You are getting confused. $N$ here is playing the role of the identity element of the quotient group $G/N$, so of course $N^k=N$ for all integers $k$. In any group, all powers of the identity element are equal to the identity.

Comment: Oh! I see. If you're working in the quotient , it(s fine. That was not explicit.